# How do I see the event label of a dynamic element for Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, dynamic, event-tracking, real-time

On our webpage we installed a remarketing banner through Marketo that would appear if certain criteria are met (user adds item to cart then abandons it to go to another page on our site). I'm trying to track clicks on this banner through Google Analytics events and I believe the event label is needed. The colleague who worked on this banner is no longer with the organization. Does anyone know where I can find this event label? Would it be something that's set up in Marketo or a piece of code inserted directly on the webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Does the site use [Google Tag Manager](https://www.google.com/analytics/tag-manager/)? GA Events can be configured in GTM which technically is inserted directly on the page, but may be harder to spot than just viewing the source.

Also, you can install a Chrome Extension like: [Google Analytics Logger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-logger/mnocefeloijpdenhbidaoildegppmkoi?hl=en-GB) and see what events fire as you click around your website.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be somewhere in the source code for the site.   It will probably be in JavaScript.  From https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events, the code for sending an event usually looks something like

`ga('send', 'event', [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue], [fieldsObject]);`

or

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Videos',
  eventAction: 'play',
  eventLabel: 'Fall Campaign'
});
```

Keep in mind that the JavaScript could be pulling the event name from another source.  `eventLabel: $(this).data('event-name')` would mean that it is pulling from the HTML attribute data-event-name on the HTML element.

Another way to figure it out would be to use real time analytics.  Visit the "Real Time" -> "Events" report in Google Analytics:

[image]

While that report is open, click on the banner on your website in another window or tab.     The event should show up in the report as you watch.